# Sharepoint online email integration with Office 365

Tags: c#, sharepoint, workflow, office365

I am currently trying to find an option on how to open an email message stored in Sharepoint Online in the outlook web app. This means that I have dragged an email message from Outlook and dragged in a SharePoint online document library. However, I would like to respond the email through SP online by simply click on the item (and then it opens in the Outlook web app).

If this is not offered out of the box, is there a way to create an app for it, example by using Outlook web api to implement this functionality please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save an email in the *.msg file format and upload the file to SharePoint Online it won't open in Outlook Web App (OWA) since OWA doesn't understand the *.msg file format (rich file format). You could download the file and open with your outlook client .

If you want to create an app to accomplish that.In c# , You could use SharePoint Client dll with below steps :

1.make a request to the SharePoint passing the Credential object which is created by username and password :

```
 ClientContext context = new ClientContext(SiteUrl);
 context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, Password);
```

2.provide file url to read the data from .msg file :

```
public Stream GetFile() 
    { 
        using (ClientContext clientContext = GetContextObject()) 
        { 

            Web web = clientContext.Web; 
            clientContext.Load(web, website => website.ServerRelativeUrl); 
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
            Regex regex = new Regex(SiteUrl, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
            string strSiteRelavtiveURL = regex.Replace(FileUrl, string.Empty); 
            string strServerRelativeURL = CombineUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl, strSiteRelavtiveURL); 

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File oFile = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(strServerRelativeURL); 
            clientContext.Load(oFile); 
            ClientResult<Stream> stream = oFile.OpenBinaryStream(); 
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
            return this.ReadFully(stream.Value); 
        } 
    }
```

3. You could download the .msg file with FileStream object(click [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/file-from-SharePoint-Online-cc418dba) to download entire demo) .After that , you could [use c# to read information from the file](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32899/Reading-an-Outlook-MSG-File-in-C) and then send email via System.Net.Mail.MailMessage:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("servername"); 
mail.From = new MailAddress(strFromAddress);
mail.To.Add(strToAddress);
mail.Subject = strSubject;
mail.Body = strMessage;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. So you mean that there is not an option to click on the item (.msg item) stored in SharePoint online and open the item in the Outlook 365 or Outlook 2013 (client) so as to reply an email from there please?

Comment: @Sambas23 AFAIK,yes , opening MSG files directly from SharePoint Online is not supported,you need to download and open using a client supporting MSG file format (such as Outlook).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Nan Yu.

Comment: However, just to ensure, is there a possible way how to do this functionality? For example using the Office 365 web api?